# how does a check button work in a Tkinter menu?

Tags: python, tkinter

**goal**

To understand how the check button works in a Tkinter menu. Especially how the value of the variable associated is changed and when the function mentioned in the command is called.

**code**

I have the following checkbutton that I have added to a Tkinter menu:

```
window = Tk()

shown = BooleanVar()
shown.set(True)        

menubar = Menu(window)


optionsmenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0) 

optionsmenu.add_checkbutton(label='Show timing after the run is completed',command=PopUp,variable=shown,onvalue = True,offvalue = False)
```

For simplicity the on value of the check button is `true` and the off value is `false`.

**what I want to know:**

1. Is the value of the variable changed when the check button is pressed or is the function called and the value of the variable needs to be changed explicitly?
2. Is the command executed before the variable is toggled or after it has been toggled??

**specs**

Windows XP SP3

Python 2.7

**Please** help me with this doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers to your questions are as so:

1. Yes the variable is changed when the check button is pressed. That is the normal behavior of the check button widget.
2. The command is called after the value of the variable has been toggled from on to off or vice versa whatsoever be the case.